# Best practice to handle ListView ItemClick in UWP using MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, events, mvvm, uwp

I need to open a new view (item details) on mouse double click in `ListView` in UWP using MVVM. In WPF I used a command with a parameter and `EventTrigger` but Microsoft does not recommended to use it in UWP:

> *Triggers, EventTrigger, Actions and BeginStoryboard are not commonly used. These API mainly exist for compatibility in XAML originally used for Microsoft Silverlight...For events in control templates, use visual states and VisualStateManager.*

As I understood it is used when you need to change visual state of the control but I need to open a new view.
How can I use `VisualStateManager` for my purpose?

There is how my XAML looked in WPF:

```
<ListBox x:Name="PersonsListControl" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonsProvider}" 
         ItemsPanel="{StaticResource PersonsListPanelTemplate}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonsListItemTemplate}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding GetPersonDetailsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UWP you can use `{x:Bind ...}` :

```
<ListBox ...
         DoubleTapped="{x:Bind HandleDoubleTapped}" />
```

And in your `ViewModel` just create a method :

```
public void HandleDoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your logic
}
```

References :
[DoubleTapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_DoubleTapped)
[ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox)

---

**EDIT:**
@JörgenSigvardsson pointed out that `x:Bind` do not bind directly to the `DataContext` and you should create a proxy property/properties to access particular data from your page.
More on that can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path-resolution)

Comment: But this isn't MVVM, is it?

Comment: Yes it is. You're binding `EventHandler` to specified method inside of your `ViewModel`. It is recommended by Microsoft itself.

Comment: [Binding in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)

Comment: `{x:Bind}` does not bind to the viewmodel (`DataContext`) by default. It binds to the page. If you want to make it MVVM, you have to expose the viewmodel as a property, and then dot into the viewmodel, e.g. `{x:Bind ViewModel.Property }`

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson I just read that on MSDocs and wasn't aware of this being changed. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Hey, fun fact!  I get a compiler error ("Object reference not set to instance of an object.") when I try to bind the **Tapped** event.

Comment: @DonaldAirey This might be issue with incompatible libraries. It has been one and a half year age when I wrote this answer. Maybe UWP API's has changed. I will investigate this later today. Can you confirm on what versions of APIs are you using?

Comment: @Mateusz - I was unable to confirm the issue on a tiny repro and I don't have time to go back and figure out why the compiler was generating the error.  I can confirm that I wiped all obj and bin directories and recompiled all and still had the problem.  That's the Achilles Heel of UWP, when something goes wrong, there's virtually no feedback that takes you to the real problem.